# How do I deploy a netcore IHosted Service console App in Azure?

Tags: azure, deployment, .net-core

I'm new into Azure (so excuse me in advance if question does not make sense) and I would like to implement self-hosted net core service for a background process using IHost without the MVC funcionallity. We are not working with containers at the moment, so the question is which is the best way to deploy this IHost service in azure,  is it possible to deploy it as an app service even if we are not using any mvc api functionallity? Thanks!

Comment: did you try it already?  Azure Web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way that meet our requirements is to deploy the self-hosted console app(IHosted Service) straight to an Azure App Service. This deployment automatically generate a Webjob(within the mention App Service) running the console app.